# C extern variable declared outside of any function

Tags: c, variables, external

I was looking at a C header file which at some point had the following declaration(the code is written by a competent person so I assume t's not a mistake.

```
#ifndef _BLABLA_
#include <stdint.h>

external uint32 x;

#endif
```

Why is the variable declared external? As long as it's defined together with a library, we can be sure it's not going to be used within another function.
Is it just coding style?

Answer (score 1):

the `extern` keyword is to make a variable shared across compilation units:

- [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable
- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/
- http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf page 31

here is the shortest example I could work out to show off how it works:

blabla.c:

```
int x = 1;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int x;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation:

```
gcc -o main main.c blabla.c
```

N.B.: it's only an example to show off how it's working, but it's not good development practice.

And I totally agree with @dasblinkenlight:

**using globals is bad practice, making it really hard to read and understand one's code (even if it is your code you're reading 6 months after). So avoid those at all costs!**

Comment: Saying that globals are bad is pretty harsh considering that lot of C usage happens in embedded world where globals are necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say to avoid them at all costs. But always onsider if you need them in that way.

Comment: @user694733 I'm actually developing *a lot* in the embedding world, and I'm fighting as much as I can the over usage of *globals* and *gotos*. It's sad that the Arduino environment has been designed so that singletons are necessarily globals whereas it could have been done differently. But Arduino is C++ and you can embed your singletons globals in namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a coding style. Unless the variable declared `external`, the compiler is going to consider the declaration a *definition* of that variable as well. Definitions of globals must be unique; if you include a header without an `extern` in several translation units (i.e. more than one .C file) you are going to get linker errors.

> we can be sure it's not going to be used within another function.

Actually, the point of declaring that variable `extern` is to let any function that included that header use the variable `x`: variables like that are considered global. Using lots of globals is a common cause of maintenance headaches, so one should be very careful to introduce them only when they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: "Definitions of globals must be unique; if you include a header without an `extern` in several translation units (i.e. more than one .C file) you are going to get linker errors." Here you forget about the [tentative definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition).

Comment: @glglgl If I remember it right, tentative definitions work within a single translation unit. If there is no definition that's definitely a definition (i.e. because it has an initializer) then the tentative definition becomes a real definition. Putting them in two translation units causes link errors.

Comment: a.c: `int tent; int * a(void) { return &tent; }` - b.c: `int tent; int * b(void) { return &tent; }` - m.c: `#include <stdio.h>
int * a(); int * b(); int tent = 4; int main() { printf("%p %p %p %d\n", a(), b(), &tent, tent); }` -> `0x804a020 0x804a020 0x804a020 4` - so at least gcc accepts it.

Comment: But you may be right - [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t598446-tentative-definition-versus-external-linkage.html) they talk about it being UB.