# What is the rationale behind tentative definitions in C?

Tags: c, variables, language-lawyer, definition

Consider following program. Will this give any compilation errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int s=5;
int s;
int main(void)
{
     printf("%d",s);
}
```

At first glance it seems that compiler will give variable redefinition error but program is perfectly valid according to C standard. (See live demo here http://ideone.com/Xyo5SY).

A tentative definition is any external data declaration that has no storage class specifier and no initializer.

C99 6.9.2/2

> A declaration of an identiﬁer for an object that has ﬁle scope without
>   an initializer, and without a storage-class speciﬁer or with the
>   storage-class speciﬁer static, constitutes a tentative deﬁnition. If a
>   translation unit contains one or more tentative deﬁnitions for an
>   identiﬁer, and the translation unit contains no external deﬁnition for
>   that identiﬁer, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation
>   unit contains a ﬁle scope declaration of that identiﬁer, with the
>   composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an
>   initializer equal to 0.

My question is, what is rationale for allowing tentative definitions? Is there any use of this in C? Why does C allow tentative definitions?

Comment: I don't think there're any valuable reasons for that because C++ itself has never had it, among many other programming languages.

Comment: @edmz C++ is not C, nor have the two languages (even in their pre-standardized C with classes and K&R C forms) ever been compatible, so C++ has zero place in a discussion about the ANSI C standard. The reason for tentative definitions is the same reason you can still define C functions with K&R syntax (`main(c,v)int c; char **v;{ ... }`): backward-compatibility. *Actual* backward-compatibility. As in, you can run a C codebase that hasn't been touched since 1973 through a modern compiler and it will still compile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tentative definitions was created as a way to bridge incompatible models that existed pre-C89. This is covered in the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) section `6.9.2` External object definitions which says:

> Prior to C90, implementations varied widely with regard to forward
>   referencing identifiers with internal linkage (see §6.2.2). **The C89
>   committee invented the concept of tentative definition to handle this
>   situation.** A tentative definition is a declaration that may or may not
>   act as a definition: If an actual definition is found later in the
>   translation unit, then the tentative definition just acts as a
>   declaration. If not, then the tentative definition acts as an actual
>   definition. For the sake of consistency, the same rules apply to
>   identifiers with external linkage, although they're not strictly
>   necessary.

and section `6.2.2` from the C99 rationale says:

> The definition model to be used for objects with external linkage was
>   a major C89 standardization issue. The basic problem was to decide
>   which declarations of an object define storage for the object, and
>   which merely reference an existing object. A related problem was
>   whether multiple definitions of storage are allowed, or only one is
>   acceptable. **Pre-C89 implementations exhibit at least four different
>   models**, listed here in order of increasing restrictiveness:

Comment: How you know & understand C & C++ standard so well? You are really genius.

Comment: @PravasiMeet I know it well because I spend a lot of time reading the standard and the related documents and SO questions. It is just about practice and experience. The more experience you have, the more interesting problems you will get to solve and it just builds from there.

Comment: I don't think the second quote is really relevant. Tentative definitions is a feature local to one translation unit. It is a purely *compiler proper* feature, no linker involved. It has no relation to external linkage and the accompanying Ref/Def models. I don't see the Rationale in 6.2.2 drawing any connections between the Ref/Def models and tentative definitions.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of a case where it's useful:

```
void (*a)();

void bar();
void foo()
{
    a = bar;
}

static void (*a)() = foo;

/* ... code that uses a ... */
```

The key point is that the definition of `foo` has to refer to `a`, and the definition of `a` has to refer to `foo`. Similar examples with initialized structures should also be possible.

Comment: In this specific case, you could avoid the need for a tentative declaration by adding an `extern` to the first line (making it just a declaration).  Where you really need the tentative declaration is if you want `a` to be `static` (file scope)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Yes, I missed that. I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: Another way to avoid this would be `void foo(); void (*a)() = foo;`

Comment: `error: static declaration of 'a' follows non-static declaration`

Comment: Possibly one more example where it is useful: `struct x x; struct x { char x[ sizeof( &x ) ]; };`. Note: MSVC fails to compile this. Note: MSVC team won't fix it.