# Can a tentative definition use the storage class specifier _Thread_local?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration

The C17 draft states the following (6.9.2, ¶2):

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*. [...]

There are 5 storage class specifiers: `extern`, `static`, `_Thread_local`, `register`, `auto`. Of these, only the former 3 can occur at file scope. Outside of all functions, `_Thread_local` can – but needn't be – combined with `extern` or `static`. Hence, for tentative definitions, there are the following possibilities in terms of storage class specifiers:

```c
int i1; // tentative definition, external linkage
extern int i2; // non-definition declaration, external linkage
static int i3; // tentative definition, internal linkage
_Thread_local int i4; // ?, external linkage
_Thread_local extern int i5; // ?, external linkage
_Thread_local static int i6; // ?, internal linkage
```

(Note here that the keyword `_Thread_local` doesn't influence linkage.)

The declarations of `i1` and `i3` are tentative definitions. But what about `i4`, `i5`, `i6` – are their declarations tentative definitions? Why or why not?

I am guessing that the answer for `i5` is 'no', because neither of the two conditions

- has no storage class specifier
- has the storage class specifier `static`

applies. But I'm unsure about `i4` and `i6`.

Comment: How can there be any question about `i4`? Its declaration has `_Thread_local` and does not have `static`. `_Thread_local` is a storage-class specifier. The rule for a tentative definition is it is without a storage-class specifier or with `static`. `i4` satisfies neither of those. `i6` does have `static`, so it satisfies “without a storage-class specifier or with storage-class specifier `static`”, so the only question would be whether there is some ambiguity of natural language in the use of “or”.

Comment: Compiling with `clang -fcommon` (Apple Clang 11) and linking the resulting object file with itself (`ld -r x.o x.o`) results in a duplicate symbol error for `i4` and not for the others, indicating the compiler treated all but `i4` as tentative definitions or other non-definition declarations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The reason why I am unsure about `i4` is that it is possible that the authors of the standard simply forgot to think about `_Thread_local`. *If* `_Thread_local` is irrelevant for this question, the declaration of `i4` is like that of `i1`. The reason why I am asking about `i6` is that I am wondering whether the standard's wording "with" is to be interpreted as "with only", for essentially the same reason.

Comment: (When they came up with the notion of a "tentative definition", which happened for historical reasons, the keyword `_Thread_local` didn't yet exist. For this reason, it will be interesting to see how to fit it in.)

Comment: `that it is possible that the authors of the standard simply forgot` That is totally, very much possible, but is kind of irrelevant. The standard text is what it is.

Comment: @KamilCuk Fair enough, but I asked this question with the possibility in mind that there might be other parts of the standard, including its examples, that (by the principle of consistency) force a particular interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

> what about i4, i5, i6

```
_Thread_local int i4;
```

- not `without a storage-class specifier`
- not `with the storage-class specifier static`
- not tentative

---

```
  _Thread_local extern int i5;
```

- not `without a storage-class specifier`
- not `with the storage-class specifier static`
- not tentative

---

```
  _Thread_local static int i6;
```

- not `without a storage-class specifier`
- `with the storage-class specifier static`
- is tentative

> Can a tentative definition use the storage class specifier _Thread_local?

Sure.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a tentative definition use the storage class specifier _Thread_local?

#### In C17

**Yes, provided that the declaration in question also includes `static`.**

The definition of "tentative definition" is:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*.

(C17 6.9.2/2)

`_Thread_local` is a storage-class specifier (C17 6.7.1/1), so a declaration that includes `_Thread_local` does not satisfy the criterion "without a storage-class specifier". For the most part, a declaration may include at most one storage-class specifier, but `_Thread_local` may be combined with either `static` or `extern` (C17 6.7.1/2), and a declaration that has both `_Thread_local` and `static` does satisfy the criterion "[or] with the storage-class specifier `static`".

Taking your examples one by one, and assuming them to appear at file scope:

- `int i1;` - no initializer and no storage-class specifier.  **This is a tentative definition.**
- `extern int i2;` - storage class specifier `extern`.  **This is *not* a tentative definition.**
- `static int i3;` - no initializer and `static`. **This is a tentative definition.**
- `_Thread_local int i4;` - `_Thread_local` and not `static`.  **This is *not* a tentative definition,** though perhaps that's a defect in the spec.
- `_Thread_local extern int i5;` - both `_Thread_local` and `extern`, but not `static`. **This is *not* a tentative definition**.
- `_Thread_local static int i6;` - no initializer and `static`.  **This is a tentative definition,** though perhaps that's a defect in the spec.

> I am guessing [...]

There's really no need here to guess about what the spec says.  The wording is clear and simple.  You might wonder about whether the spec is defective regarding some of the `_Thread_local` cases, but that's a different question.  And that leads to ...

#### In C2X

The relevant specifications will change in C2X.  There, the language is instead:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without the storage-class specifier `extern` or `thread_local`, constitutes a tentative definition.

(C2X 6.9.2/2)

In C2X, `_Thread_local` is classified as an "alternative spelling" of `thread_local` (C2X 6.4.1/3), so it is immaterial that C2X expresses paragraph 6.9.2/2 in terms of `thread_local` instead of `_Thread_local`.  In this version of the language, declarations that include `_Thread_local` or `thread_local` are expressly excluded from being tentative definitions.

We can suppose, then, that the language in C17 (and C11) that allowed tentative definitions of static thread-locals was probably an oversight, introduced with the `_Thread_local` storage-class specifier and the allowance for it to appear together with `static`.  Having recognized this issue, and the corresponding change in C2X, I would be disinclined to rely on tentative definitions of thread-locals even in conjunction with versions of C that, in principle, permit them.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the other answers, let me take a guess at what happened historically:

- The notion of a *tentative definition* was introduced for historical reasons (there many possible references one could provide, eg: [What is the rationale behind tentative definitions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33200738/2057969)).
- The keyword `_Thread_local` was introduced with C11 (which C17 is a corrected version of, without substantial additions).
- If the definition of 'tentative definition' (C17 draft, 6.9.2, ¶2) is taken literally, the answer is clear – though when asking I was wondering whether there are other parts of the standard that encourage a different interpretation or outright contradict the definition, because the wording looks like there was an oversight.
- If `_Thread_local` was orthogonal to the notion of a "tentative definition", `i4` and `i6` would be tentative definitions, while `i5` would not.

Let me summarize everything in a table:

| Tentative definition? | C17 draft, 6.9.2 ¶2; literal interpretation | C17 draft, 6.9.2 ¶2; modified to assume that `_Thread_local` is orthogonal to the definition | C23 draft (`n3096.pdf`), 6.9.2 ¶2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `int i1;` | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| `extern int i2;` | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ |
| `static int i3;` | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| `_Thread_local int i4;` | ✗ | ✓ | ✗ |
| `_Thread_local extern int i5;` | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ |
| `_Thread_local static int i6;` | ✓ | ✓ | ✗ |

The left-hand column indicates what some of our language lawyers argue for regarding C17 – I acknowledge this as a reasonable view. The middle column represents one possible interpretation I suspected when formulating my question, namely that `_Thread_local` has no bearing on the issue. The right-hand column represents what C23 will likely be like.

Given what the C23 (or C2x) standard draft `n3096.pdf` says, it is safe to assume that the C17 standard was carelessly edited/worded in this regard.

As for *why*, please allow me to speculate: Originally different compilers handled multiple declarations/definitions differently, which necessitated the notion of a "tentative definition" in the standard. 'Thread-local' storage duration was introduced so long after this that C23 perhaps makes the reasonable assumption that the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier appears mainly in code that doesn't rely on tentative definitions. Or the standards committee just wanted to make life easier for compiler writers.