# Why is a datatype necessary for an initialization that follows a declaration?

Tags: c

Consider the simple C program:

```
int a;      // declaration
int a = 11; // initialization

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int b;  // declaration
    b = 10; // assignment
```

If the initialization of `a` were written without the data type, such as `a = 11`, the compiler raises a warning. Why does the initialization of `a` require a data type, when the declaration of `a` already specifies its data type?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about your question, but to write a code out side of function scope....

Comment: For C++ there is `auto` keyword, which does basically this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3095861/3185968

Comment: @arrowd: I really don't see the connection to auto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int a` at file scope is a "tentative" definition (because it lacks the initialising part). This means that `a` can be defined again with a value at a later point.

A tentative definition may or may not act as a definition, depending on whether there is an actual external definition before or after it in the translation unit:

```
int a = 5; // defines a in the current translation unit with external linkage and a value of 5
int a; // tentative definition with no effect (a is already defined)
```

The other way around usually has more practical merit:

```
int a;
...
int a = 5;
```

The tentative definition could precede the actual definition, if, for example, the constant used to initialise it is not available at the first point.

**Edit:**

You seem to be confused that you are not able perform an assignment at file scope. A C program is allowed to have actual operations only within functions. At file scope, one may only define or declare variables, types and functions.

Comment: I don't see how this answers "Why does the initialization of a require a data type, when the declaration of a already specifies its data type?"

Comment: I really don't see how this would have any practical merit in any situation.

Comment: @Lundin: Imagine a situation where you are including an automatically generated chunk of code at the end (with the initialisation), but functions prior to it need to access `a`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has something to do with the fact that you can't write instructions in the global scope. What it means is :

```
int a = 11;
```

Defines a variable. This tells the compiler to assign a static address to the variable, because it is global. The default (assignment) value is just an added bonus.
Whereas :

```
a = 11;
```

Is an instruction, which is illegal.

Comment: But I'm asking why the compiler needs the datatype in subsequent declarations / initialization, when it has already seen the variable's datatype. I'm not asking why assignment is illegal outside of a function body.

Answer (score -3):

as your example:

```
int a; // <--- is a declaration
int a = 11; // <--- is reference to a const value
```

you can write code as this:
    int a;

```
int main() {
  a = 11;   // <--- simply no warning.
  return 0; 
}
```

That because 
  a = 1;  // <--- is a code statement
  int a = 1;  // <--- is a ref to const value

In c, you may not write assignment out of function scope.

Comment: You are mixing stuff here, there is no constants defined in your code. There are two simple ways in C to define constants, using **#define** preprocessor or using **const** keyword.