# Global variable declaration in c

Tags: c, global-variables, declaration, variable-declaration, redeclaration

```
#include<stdio.h>
int check,check;
void main(){
    printf("Hello!!");
}
```

When I compile this piece of code, everything goes on normal but when I give this inside the main function,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int check,check;
    printf("Hello!!");
}
```

I get an error like

```
C:\MinGW\bin>cc ex1.c
ex1.c: In function 'main':
ex1.c:4:11: error: redeclaration of 'check' with no linkage
 int check,check;
           ^
ex1.c:4:5: note: previous declaration of 'check' was here
 int check,check;
     ^
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You are declaring 2 variables with the same name. Name of variable can contain only underscore, letters and digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in global scope, because that is considered an tentative definition.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.2

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a
>   tentative definition.

However, in the block scope (*function scope*), there's no tentative definition, hence the code *tries to* create two identifiers with the same name which is cause for the re-declaration error, because they actually denote the same object.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095861/2173917).

That said, since `C99`, for hosted enviroments, `void main()` is not a valid signature anymore, it has to be `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: To make it clear: The two `check` at file scope denote **the same** object! (and "function scope" is too restrictive. That is always true for block scope)