# Why is the storage class of global variables in C implicitly defined as "extern"?

Tags: c, scope, global-variables, extern

When we declare any global variable, for instance

```
int x;
```

it is equivalent to

```
extern int x;
```

Now by default global variables are initialized to 0 by the compiler, which means they are allocated memory. But if I simply write

```
extern int x;
```

then this will only declare the variable, while no memory would be allocated to it.  So, my query is that if I write **extern** before `int x` or I do not write it, **in case of global variables**, how is the compiler treating them differently?  In the case where I simply write `int x`, it allocates memory and simultaneously it puts **extern** before `int x`, while in the case where I write `extern int x`, it only declares the variable while no memory is allocated to it. Please clarify how the compiler is behaving in both ways.

Comment: `int x;` is not equivalent to `extern int x;`  (you seem to acknowledge this in your last paragraph)

Comment: the question is why do you think a global variable is declared as `extern`?

Answer (score 7):

The very premise of your question is incorrect. This

```
int x;
```

is a tentative *definition* (which will turn into a normal definition of `x` by the end of the translation unit).

This

```
extern int x;
```

is a non-defining *declaration*, which is not a definition at all.

They are not even remotely equivalent.

A loose equivalent of your original definition would be

```
extern int x = 0;
```

This is a definition. But this is not an exact equivalent, since this definition is not tentative.

Keyword `extern` turns an object definition into a non-defining declaration if (and only if), there is no explicit initializer. If an explicit initializer is present, a definition remains a definition, even if you add `extern` to it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be answered by understanding external object definition and [Tentative definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095861/2173917).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has **file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier** or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and **the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.**

Comment: I wander why people still ignores the fact that the Standard should be read at least one time.

Comment: @Michi Agree. Many a times the standard text seems a bit tricky but upon careful study, that is the one authoritative source which can actually answer most of the questions.