# Is a extern variable with initialization really a definition?

Tags: c++

I know a variable with initialization is a definition no matter if it is `extern`. However, since `extern int x=1;` is a definition, why doesn't the compiler throw redefinition error running the following code?

```
//ok,no error
int x;
extern int x=1;
int main()
{
}

//however,this is an error
extern int x=1;
int x;
int main()
{
}
```

Why can this happen? Is there any difference?

**Update**:You are right.When I compile with VS 2013,there is no error.Now I tried with gcc on linux and got an redefinition error just as I expected.

Just as @Bo Persson said,it's all about tentative definition in C. And when I change the file suffix to .c, gcc takes it as a warning rather than an error and it can be compiled.

Comment: They are both errors.

Comment: first throws error, too: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99912d81a14f3a04

Comment: In the C language you have a [Tentative definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition). Perhaps the compiler allows this in C++ a well, for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, both of your snippets are ill-formed - please use a modern compiler to try them out.

- [first snippet on **wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sCCBF4GJDnI99eP6)
- [second snippet on **wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jHnscw7Fs84H4yqi)

When declaring a variable in *global scope*, it is automatically zero-initialized. This is the reason you're getting a *redefinition* error - `x` is already defined to zero.

The following snippet will compile:

```
extern int x;
int x;
int main()
{
}
```