# Is my understanding of declaration and definition correct?

Tags: c, declaration, multiple-definition-error

As per my understanding when you say ;

```
int var;          // it is a declaration because no value stored in var
```

But when you do ;

```
int var = 90;     // it is a definition because var got its value
```

Reason to ask this question is that I am following book and internet for programming. But, I see everywhere different meaning of definition and declaration. Please clarify , If you know better ?

Some people are saying that both are definitions , if that's the case why program below gives " redeclaration error " instead of "redifination error" in gcc.

```
int main(){
  int var = 100;
  int var;

  return 0;
}
```

Error while compiling :

[image]

Comment: No, your understanding is incorrect. Both are definitions, one with an initializer and one without. See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: Actually None Of Them is Declaration

Comment: @SurajJain, Both of them are declarations, but they're also definitions. The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @chris Yes Definition itself contains declaration , am i right

Comment: @SurajJain, I recommend taking a look at Igor's link for more detail :) *Definitions are declarations that...*

Comment: @chris Can You Check My Answer Below

Comment: The correct complete answer differs between C and C++.   Which **one** do you want?

Comment: @chux I want answer related to C

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C has a feature called "tentative declaration" which allows you to declare a variable multiple times provided no more than once it is initialised (which should be the last one).

Comment: I thought answer for all the programming language will be same. That's why I tagged c and c++

Comment: @WeAreRight so why not add PHP too?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Frankly speaking I was thinking to add PHP because I write PHP codes ! Tags modified by the way........

Comment: @WeAreRight I know, because I was one of the approvers.

Comment: Again hammered to a C/C++ question that doesn't answer the **C** :(

Comment: `int var;` later followed by `extern int var;` in file scope is not a definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition

Answer (score 1):

Weather it is declaring or defining that all depends upon where you are using it . weather it is a global variable for same program or an extern variable of other program .
case 1

```
int var; 
main ()
```

The line int var; both declares and defines the variable; it effectively says, "create a variable named var, of type int. Also, the storage for the variable is that it is a global variable defined in the object file associated with this source file
.

case 2

```
extern int var;
main()
```

but here it is declaring the variable but not defining it . so it all depends on where you are using this

Comment: `int var;` is not a definition. It is a "tentative definition", which means that it might not be definition after all..

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A tentative definition is a definition. "tentative" is an adjective

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, `int var;` and `int var = 90;` are both definitions.  You get a compilation error for having two definitions of `var` in the same scope.  Note that they are also both declarations (all definitions are declarations).

The same syntax has different meaning outside of a function, which might be why you got confused.

Answer (score 0):

No, your understanding of declarations and definitions is incorrect.

The line

```
int var;
```

is a declaration.    It may ALSO be a definition depending on context (since all definitions are declarations).   For example, in;

```
int var;
int main()
{

}
```

the declaration of `var` is a *tentative definition* of a variable `var` that has external linkage.    In the context above, it is actually a definition.   However, if we modify the code to be;

```
int var = 42;
int var;

int main()
{

}
```

then `int var = 42` is a definition with initialiser (of `42`) and the following tentative definition `int var` becomes a declaration but not a definition.   This is also true if the two lines `int var` and `int var = 42` are swapped.

Even better, the meaning changes if `int var` is placed inside a function.  For example;

```
int main()
{
    int var;
}
```

In this context, `int var` is a definition of a variable, `var`, of automatic storage duration.    Placing a second definition of `var` in the same scope is illegal.

```
int main()
{
    int var;          /* definition */
    int var = 42;     /*  second definition - illegal */
}
```