# Declaration and Definition C Lang

Tags: c

I know there has been awfully lot debates over the differences and meanings of Declaration and Definition but ***I still can't understand where and when should we use Declaration.***

**Declaration**

> A variable declaration provides assurance to the compiler that there exists a variable with the given type and name so that the compiler can proceed for further compilation without requiring the complete detail about the variable. A variable definition has its meaning at the time of compilation only, the compiler needs actual variable definition at the time of linking the program.

**Definition**

> A variable definition tells the compiler where and how much storage to create for the variable. A variable definition specifies a data type and contains a list of one or more variables of that type as follows −

EDIT 1:
 Is declaration necessary at all times, if not, when it is necessary to use? Does definition do enough job as it does in other languages like Java, JS

EDIT 2:
 I have already said that there have been answers to their differences, I have problems about understanding their usages.

Comment: I dont worry about them in the context of variables anymore... it was a big deal in C89 and older, but basically they are the same in most places now... with the exception of something that is `extern` or has the type masked from the interface, like an opaque struct or an object handle that is passed around as `(void *)`

Comment: There are no debates, it is defined straight and clear. Look at the duplicate I am going to propose...

Comment: I can go with that dup, good answers there

Comment: I saw that q but I still have problems about their usages

Comment: Well, I am probably going to get some fire here, but I would say that you can successfully use it intuitively, without understanding it.

Comment: A declaration says there is a "thing" somewhere. A definition **is** the thing.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: And then there is [tentative definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition)....

Comment: A C compiler won't look forwards to find things that haven't been mentioned yet. If I have a function foo that calls a function bar, then my options are either to 1) put (define) bar in the .c file first, so that when we get to foo the compiler will already know what bar is, or 2) declare bar first, then write function foo, then write function bar afterwards. If I just write function foo then function bar then when we get to the bar call inside foo the compiler will error out.

Comment: @Rup can you post that comment with a short code example as an answer I cant imagine it like this

Comment: The question is closed now so I can't. Was roughly like program 1 and program 2 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41463559

Comment: "Is declaration necessary at all times, if not, when it is necessary to use?" No. needed when item used before definition.

Comment: @DavidBowling  Yes, comment deleted and re commented.

Comment: Looking at the "EDIT 3" I would say we have an XY-problem here. There is a clear confusion between "definition" and "initialization".

Comment: I think I'm going to give up.... Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is there a documentation or a good source I can dig?

Comment: @aomerk You just need to ask the right question. Looks like your real question is about the storage classes and the usage of unitialized variables. Should be covered in any decent C textbook

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually, I know the usage of unitialized variables and their results but I just got lost after some point in this question. Sorry.

Comment: @aomerk -- "Is there a documentation or a good source I can dig?": [yes](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).