# How to understand C language redefinition and redeclaration error?

Tags: c, declaration, definition, redefinition

I'm not really sure am I right, but i think that: in the line `static int k;` variable is declared and defined (`k` is initialized by default to 0); in the next line `static int k = 31;` I initialized `k` to 31 (why this is not redefinition?); in the next line nothing is actually changed because it's just another declaration of `k` - i've read somewhere that multiple declarations are allowed sometimes (if you can tell me when and where).

```
static int k;
static int k = 31;
static int k;
int main()
{
    static int k;
    static int k = 21;
    static int k;
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Why I didn't get an error for the line `static int k = 31;` for redefinition? On the other hand, if it works properly for global variable `k` why I'm getting redeclaration error for the line `static int k = 21;` for local `k`. Can someone explain this so I can understand even if I'm just a beginner in C?

Comment: For reference to the _tentative definition_ concept there are other SO posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition for example.

Comment: _Why I didn't get an error for the line static int k = 31; for redefinition?_ Because this `static int k = 31;` is strong symbol(`static` with *initialized*) & compiler give preference to strong symbol over weak one(un-initialized).