# Declaring global variables in C using extern

Tags: c

From this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) , the best way to declare global variables in C is to declare the variable in 1 header using `extern`, and define it in 1 source only. Then reference the header in other source files wanting to use the global variable.

So I did that, in my header `global.h`:

```
extern Boolean transmitting;
```

Inside my `main.c`, I defined it inside my main function:

```
int main() {
    Boolean transmitting = FALSE;
...
}
```

However, I get a warning on the variable in the main `"unused variable 'transmitting' [-Wunused-variable]"` which tells me this is only defined in the scope of the main, so other source files cant use it? Does this mean I need to define them outside `main()`?

Previoulsy, **I was not using the extern keyword to declare in my header** and used the variable in my main like this:

```
int main() {
    transmitting = FALSE;
...
}
```

Everything worked fine and other source files had access to the variable by including this header. However I want to use the correct method of declaring global variables. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Global variables need to be defined outside of any function. Anything you define within a function (even main) is a local variable and can never be visible from outside that function

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the variable at global scope, i.e. outside the main() function.

Comment: What about my previous approach? Is it really bad practice?

Comment: Well, it simply does not work like that.  Global variables must be declared at global scope.

Comment: Its still not clear to me since when I defined my global variables without extern in a header, gave them a value in the main, and so all the other sources that included this 1 header actually printed the correct value of the variable whenever a source changed it. With this behavior, it doesn't seem like I'm "defining the same variable in multiple files". It seems like these vars are really global without using extern.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz I think what you desccribe here would be "tentative definitions" of the variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you declared two different variables. In main function, it's local variable that is limited in scope of `main`.

See the results of program below, the address of two variable are different:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
extern bool transmitting;

void print_transmitting() {
  printf("extern transmitting addr= %p\n", &transmitting);
}
int main(void) {
    bool transmitting = false;
    print_transmitting();
    printf("in main function, transmitting addr = %p\n", &transmitting);
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

```
extern transmitting addr= 0x563bc90ce011
in main function, transmitting addr = 0x7ffd251fb367
```

As the answer of @Marc Balmer, you must declare the variable at global scope, i.e. outside the main() function.