# C programming Scope of global variable in multiple c files

Tags: c

Hi I have some experience in C programming.  But this behavior is haunting for some time.  I have two c files:

```
// file 1.c 
int a = 10;
int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

```
// file 2.c 
int a = 20;
```

I compile these two files with the following gcc command:

```
gcc -o out file1.c file2.c
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchLeVss.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `a'; /tmp/ccvLYpYo.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I remove the initialization of the variable 'a' in both files, like so:

```
// file 1.c 
int a;

// file2.c
int a;
```

then I don't get any compilation errors.  Can anyone explain how the compiler treats the variable 'a' declared in two files with and without initialization?

Comment: May have something to do with this:  [About Tentative definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition) This answer also has an explanation under "Not so good... [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/920069)

Comment: @vivec is it do difference if you try to actually use 'a' somewhere?

Comment: @vivek have you tried to declare the variable `static`? As in `static int a`. That way it becomes file local and is not exposed outside the translation unit.